# Change the color of an image in php?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

How can i change the color of a clipart in a image ,this image has red color heart in it http://www.tutorialpark.com/wp-content/uploads/3/Heart-Blending.jpg i want to change from red to blue in php Thanks. Mostly my images will be in png format.

Comment: This is not a trivial task. Please provide an example of what it's supposed to look like, and (if you already know) what colorization method you want to use. Also, can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: What are colorization method? actually i was trying to make like this http://www.buildasign.com/PowerDesign.aspx?T=62755647584E45667173636D4575386E63476D7533673D3D&cid=1898 there is heart in it and you can change color

Comment: Looking at your link, that happens in the browser so it's probably done in JavaScript, not PHP. As a workaround - if you just want two different colors, can you save two images on your server (one red, one blue) and load the correct one depending on which color you want?

Comment: Maybe the ImageMagick examples can help you:  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#opaque

Comment: @MW thanks Wow thats good answer yes i can do that thanks. Thanks for help

Comment: @Pekka thanks for help i will surely look at that thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5 you could use the imagefilter function with the filter, called "IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE". If you dont have PHP5 you could do it manually.

A user, called Bartman did the following solution, which works as far as I tested it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php#93134

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the image you can use imagefill() or imagefilltoborder ().
Check this.

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/8

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my script](https://github.com/1fer/wp_image_color_replace/blob/master/includes/replacecolor) if you have installed Imagick Library in your server. You can invoke it with:

```
./replacecolor -i "{what color shold be replaced}" -o "{to what color}" -f 40 -g 50 {path to img} {path to new image}
```

example:
[image]